Export whole container of docker instance
I have problem to export whole instance of docker container. I use docker export but its exports only image - still use internet to download missing things (from s3 and gitlab) for build whole app. I don't have access to internet on local machine so I won't to copy whole container - from one computer to pendrive and than to my local server. Anyone can help me how can I do this ?

docker export should export all the filesystem content of the container, even if modified at runtime, that's the point. If your container had volumes attached to it, though those won't be exported and need to transferred separately.

Can you provide a [mcve]? What content is not included and what is using the internet to download from s3 and gitlab? Do you need to export the container, or would you be better off saving the image?

A container is normally a wrapper around a process; there shouldn't normally be anything of interest in the container filesystem that docker export would preserve.  In the same way that you'd ^C a process on one system and start a new process on another one, can you just docker run a new container on the other system?

so If I understand correctly I need to export container with image and volume attached separately for all data included to it ?

If I understand correctly, you want to transfer the docker image as described in this tutorial
In case this link goes down, here's a tl;dr:

use docker save registry/image:tag --output ./image-tag.tar on one machine to export all layers to a .tar file
transfer that file to the other machine
import it via docker load --input ./image-tag.tar

